# How does C# UdpClient.Receive work when broadcaster reboots?

Tags: c#, multicast, udpclient

I'm writing an application that needs to receive multicast data from a piece of hardware.  I have it working fine.  Occasionally, outside of the control of my application, the hardware that is broadcasting will reboot.  It is my understanding from reading the documentation that the `UdpClient.Receive` method will block until it receives data. So I am assuming that when the hardware reboots, this line of code will block. Eventually when the hardware is back online and broadcasting again, my application should start up again at that line. Is this correct? Am I not understanding something? What I am seeing in my application is that this line blocks and it never picks up again, even after the hardware reboots. Here is a code snippet.

```
IPAddress _groupAddress = IPAddress.Parse("172.16.20.1");
UdpClient _client = new UdpClient(7095);
IPEndPoint _ep = new IPEndPoint(_groupAddress, 7095);
_client.JoinMulticastGroup(_groupAddress);
bool _cancelled = false;

while (!_cancelled)
{
    byte[] _bytes = _client.Receive(ref _ep);

    ..process bytes..
}
```

Comment: Just a guess: IF your broadcaster is the default router THEN you will need to rejoin the MultiCastGroup after a reboot since it will loose any memory of MultiCastGroup members registered before the reboot!

Comment: @Yahia - hmm...that could be it.  But how would my code know when to rejoin the MultiCastGroup? Is there some way to react to a very long block in the Receive method? (the reboot usually takes between 1 and 2 minutes)

Comment: @CoreyBurnett IF you are on .NET 4.5 you could use [`ReceiveAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receiveasync.aspx) together with a "watchdog thread" to detect a gap of 1 minute (for example) of receiving no data...

Comment: iirc, if you put data into the _ep you use as a ref for the receive, it serves as a filter only showing you the packets aimed at that address/port. a broadcast usually has a 255 at the end of the address, so it might be that it gets filtered out. have you looked at it in wireshark to check if there is actually something received?